# Google Form list question to send different data from displayed value on select option

Tags: google-forms

Is there a way to have a Google Form list-type question pass different values on the backend (e.g., to its linked Google Spreadsheet) than what are displayed?

For example, under Provinces at

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1r-Lab6FPRSWP69ihPEZ0SPLJoQzsf3C1S1XjLDT8Zuc/viewform

It would be great if the HTML `<select ...>` option of

```
<option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
```

would instead get rendered as:

```
<option value="QC">Quebec</option>
```

Comment: non-answer: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/mKCIymP2Ofo/zJqUqGmMPGAJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script that changes the names in abbreviations after all forms have been submitted.
It has been done for the States of USA.
See for the code on Github:
https://github.com/davegaeddert/google-sheets-us-states/blob/master/Code.gs

Answer (score 2):

No, Google Forms just pass the values that were picked by the user: those that were shown in the form.

---

As was said in Google Products forum, to have another form of response in the spreadsheet, one needs the conversion to happen in the spreadsheet. A typical scenario is adding a sheet, e.g., named Conversion where column A has the form input and column B has what you want to see. Then do something like

```
 =arrayformula(vlookup(filter(C1:C, len(C1:C)), Conversion!A1:B, 2, False))
```

to convert column C of the Form Responses sheet. The performance will be improved if the Conversion sheet is sorted by column A, in which case `False` parameter should be dropped.

Comment: Good detailed answer too. Although this may open up another can of worms for me: not sure how transparent these cell formulas will be for my downstream backend processing 1. using a simple URL with only QueryString to export into a CSV that further gets parsed, and 2. behavior via Google Docs API, eg. in Ruby on Rails.  Thus it is not the (interim) Google spreadsheet that matters to our system.